# Search and Replace Arabic in PHP

Tags: php

I am doing a search and replace of a variable.

```
$search  = array('ي');
$replace = array('G');

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $building);
```

`$building` has the value of `ي0009`

The expected output is: `0009G`, instead the output is `G0009`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like the replacement turned off RTL ;-)

Comment: Arabic language ist RTL (right to left) and other (western) languages are LTR (left to right)...

Comment: I know what the problem is, I am asking for a solution @Havelock

Comment: "Can not reproduce" it [works with diverse PHP versions](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8hQu5d)... What about your file/input encoding? Also str_replace [works perfectly](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#109937) with UTF-8...

Comment: The first character of your string is actually ي , followed by 0009.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with multibyte encodings you must use `mb_str_replace()` directly, or ensure you got multibyte extension enabled.

You may set  string functions to be automatically overloaded by multibyte counterparts as this is supported by PHP and documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Comment: With all due respect, it's rubbish. First [`str_repalce`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#109937) works perfectly fine with multibyte strings. Second, since you're proposing to overload with `mb_str_replace`, would you please post a link to the documentation or implementation of the proposed function.